# i want to use text entered by the user on one screen in other screens too as a title(button or a label)

Tags: python, kivy

currently i am storing all the text input by the user in a file.
when i run this code the screenfive buttons text root.a and root.b are the previous entries but not the present textinput entered.

meaning that in the first execution i had input firstname1 and lastname1 on the screen four.in the screen five's button i see  with  ( with )
because this is the first time the files are created so there is no text in them.

in the second execution i type fistname2 and lastname2 in screen four but when i move to screen five it displays 'firstname1 with firstname1' in the button's text but i am expecting 'firstname2 with lastname2' which was what i entered during the present execution
this is the python code:

```
 from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen, FadeTransition

from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.uix.scatter import Scatter
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.config import Config
from kivy.base import runTouchApp

from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty, NumericProperty, StringProperty


root = FloatLayout()

class ScreenManagement(ScreenManager):
    pass

class A(Screen):
    pass

class B(Screen):
    pass

class C(Screen):
    pass

class ScreenFour(Screen):
    group_text_input = ObjectProperty()
    disability_text_input = ObjectProperty()

    grouptextinput = StringProperty('')
    disabilitytextinput = StringProperty('')

    global grouptextinput, disabilitytextinput

    def submit_textinput(self):
        self.grouptextinput = self.group_text_input.text
        print("group of people: {}".format(self.grouptextinput))
        self.save()

        self.disabilitytextinput = self.disability_text_input.text
        print("with following disability: {}".format(self.disabilitytextinput))
        self.save2()

    def save(self):
        with open("grouptextinput.txt", "w") as fobj:
            fobj.write(str(self.grouptextinput))
    def save2(self):
        with open("disabilitytextinput.txt", "w") as fobj:
            fobj.write(str(self.disabilitytextinput))            
    pass

class Help(Screen):
    pass

class ScreenFive(Screen):
    box = ScreenFour()
    a = StringProperty()
    b = StringProperty()


    myfile = open('grouptextinput.txt','r')
    print 'file is opened'
    a = myfile.readline(14)
    print a

    myfile = open('disabilitytextinput.txt','r')
    print 'file is opened'
    b = myfile.readline(14)
    print b

##    a = box.grouptextinput
##    b = box.grouptextinput

    pass

class ScreenSix(Screen):
    pass

class One(Screen):
    a = StringProperty()
    b = StringProperty()


    myfile = open('grouptextinput.txt','r')
    a = myfile.readline(14)

    myfile = open('disabilitytextinput.txt','r')
    b = myfile.readline(14)

    pass

class Two(Screen):
    a = StringProperty()
    b = StringProperty()


    myfile = open('grouptextinput.txt','r')
    a = myfile.readline(14)

    myfile = open('disabilitytextinput.txt','r')
    b = myfile.readline(14)

    pass

class Three(Screen):
    a = StringProperty()
    b = StringProperty()


    myfile = open('grouptextinput.txt','r')
    a = myfile.readline(14)

    myfile = open('disabilitytextinput.txt','r')
    b = myfile.readline(14)

    pass

class Four(Screen):
    a = StringProperty()
    b = StringProperty()


    myfile = open('grouptextinput.txt','r')
    a = myfile.readline(14)

    myfile = open('disabilitytextinput.txt','r')
    b = myfile.readline(14)

    pass

class Five(Screen):
    a = StringProperty()
    b = StringProperty()


    myfile = open('grouptextinput.txt','r')
    a = myfile.readline(14)

    myfile = open('disabilitytextinput.txt','r')
    b = myfile.readline(14)

    pass

class Six(Screen):
    a = StringProperty()
    b = StringProperty()


    myfile = open('grouptextinput.txt','r')
    a = myfile.readline(14)

    myfile = open('disabilitytextinput.txt','r')
    b = myfile.readline(14)

    pass

class Seven(Screen):
    a = StringProperty()
    b = StringProperty()


    myfile = open('grouptextinput.txt','r')
    a = myfile.readline(14)

    myfile = open('disabilitytextinput.txt','r')
    b = myfile.readline(14)

    pass

class Eight(Screen):
    a = StringProperty()
    b = StringProperty()


    myfile = open('grouptextinput.txt','r')
    a = myfile.readline(14)

    myfile = open('disabilitytextinput.txt','r')
    b = myfile.readline(14)

    pass

class Nine(Screen):
    a = StringProperty()
    b = StringProperty()


    myfile = open('grouptextinput.txt','r')
    a = myfile.readline(14)

    myfile = open('disabilitytextinput.txt','r')
    b = myfile.readline(14)

    pass

presentation = Builder.load_file("main.kv")

class MainApp(App):



    def build(self):
        return presentation

if __name__ == "__main__":
    MainApp().run()
```

and this is the kivy code:

```
#: import FadeTransition kivy.uix.screenmanager.FadeTransition

ScreenManagement:
    transition: FadeTransition()
    A:
    B:
    C:
    ScreenFour:
    Help:
    ScreenFive:
    ScreenSix:
    One:
    Two:
    Three:
    Four:
    Five:
    Six:
    Seven:
    Eight:
    Nine:

<A>:
    name: "llll"
    Button:
        on_release: app.root.current = "iiii"
        Image:
            source: '************'
            center_x: self.parent.center_x
            center_y: self.parent.center_y

<Intentions>:
    name: "iiii"
    Image:
        source: '***********'
        y: self.parent.y 
        x: self.parent.x
        allow_stretch: True
        size: 800, 750
    Button:
        text: 'Next'
        id: button
        font_size: 40
        size_hint: None, None
        on_release: app.root.current = "pppp"
        pos: 590,50
        size: 200, 60

<Picot>:
    name: "pppp"
    Image:
        source: '****************'
        y: self.parent.y 
        x: self.parent.x
        allow_stretch: True
        size: 800, 750
    Button:
        text: 'Next'
        id: button
        font_size: 40
        size_hint: None, None
        on_release: app.root.current = "screenfour"
        pos: 590,50
        size: 200, 60   

<ScreenFour>
    name: "screenfour"
    group_text_input: group
    disability_text_input: disability
    canvas.before:
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size
            source: '***************'

    Label:
        text: "**********"
        font_size: '47sp'
        pos: 0, 100
        color: 0,0,0,1
        bold: True

    TextInput:
        id: group
        multiline: False
        size_hint_x: .3
        size_hint_y: .1
        hint_text: '************'
        pos: 90, 220
        font_size: '29sp'

    Label:
        text:"********"
        font_size: '40sp'
        pos: 0, -50
        color: 0,0,0,1
        bold: True

    TextInput:
        id: disability
        multiline: True
        size_hint_x: .3
        size_hint_y: .1
        hint_text: '*********'
        pos: 465, 220
        font_size: '29sp'

    Button:
        text: 'Next'
        id: button
        font_size: 40
        size_hint: None, None
        on_release: app.root.current = "screenfive"
        on_release: root.submit_textinput()
        pos: 590,50
        size: 200, 60

    Button:
        text: 'Help!'
        id: button
        font_size: 30
        size_hint: None, None
        on_release: app.root.current = "help"
        pos: 50,50
        size: 100, 60

<Help>
    name: "help"
    Image:
        source: '******************'
        y: self.parent.y 
        x: self.parent.x
        allow_stretch: True
        size: 800, 750
    Button:
        text: '*********'
        id: button
        font_size: 40
        size_hint: None, None
        on_release: app.root.current = "screenfour"
        pos: 590,50
        size: 200, 60

<ScreenFive>
    name:"screenfive"
    canvas.before:
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size
            source: '***************'

    Label:
        text: '********'
        font_size: '60sp'
        pos: 0, 150
        color: 0,0,0,1
        bold: True

    Label:
        text: '**********'
        font_size: '53sp'
        pos: 0, 75
        color: 0,0,0,1
        bold: True

    Label:
        text: '*******'
        font_size: '60sp'
        pos: 0, 0
        color: 0,0,0,1
        bold: True

    Button:
        text: root.a + ' WITH ' + root.b
        font_size: 40
        text_size: self.width, None
        size: 760, 100
        size_hint: None, None
        pos: 20,150
        halign: 'center'
        background_color: (0, 0, 0, 1)
        color: 1, 1, 1, 1

    Button:
        text: 'Continue'
        id: button
        font_size: 40
        size: 200, 60
        size_hint: None, None
        on_release: app.root.current = "menu"
        pos: 590,50 

<ScreenSix>
    name: "menu"
    canvas:
        Color:
            rgb: .5, .5, .5
        Rectangle:
            size: self.size

    GridLayout:
        cols: 3
        spacing: 20
        padding: [20,50]
        Label:
            text: ''
        Label:
            text: '************'
            font_size: '19sp'
        Label:
            text: ''
        Button:
            text: '********'
            #on_press: root.manager.current = 'settings'
            on_release: app.root.current = "one"
        Button:
            text: '*******'
            on_release: app.root.current = "two"
        Button:
            text: '*****'
            on_release: app.root.current = "three"
        Button:
            text: '********'
            on_release: app.root.current = "four"
        Button:
            text: '********'
            on_release: app.root.current = "five"
        Button:
            text: '********'
            on_release: app.root.current = "six"
        Button:
            text: '*******'
            on_release: app.root.current = "seven"
        Button:
            text: '*********'
            on_release: app.root.current = "eight"
        Button:
            text: '***********'
            on_release: app.root.current = "nine"

<One>
    name: "one"
    Image:
        source: '********'
        y: self.parent.y
        x: self.parent.x
        allow_stretch: True

    Button:
        text: 'Back To Menu'
        id: button
        font_size: 40
        size: 300, 60
        size_hint: None, None
        on_release: app.root.current = "menu"
        pos: 100,13
        allow_stretch: True

    Button:
        text: root.a + ' WITH ' + root.b
        font_size: 40
        text_size: self.width, None
        size_hint: None, None
        halign: 'center'
        background_color: (0, 0, 0, 1)
        color: 1, 1, 1, 1
        pos: 0,520
        size: 800, 80

<Two>
    name: "two"
    Image:
        source: '*******'
        y: self.parent.y
        x: self.parent.x
        allow_stretch: True
        size: 800, 750
    Button:
        text: 'Back To Menu'
        id: button
        font_size: 40
        size: 300, 60
        size_hint: None, None
        on_release: app.root.current = "menu"
        pos: 100,13
    Button:
        text: root.a + ' WITH ' + root.b
        font_size: 40
        text_size: self.width, None
        size_hint: None, None
        halign: 'center'
        background_color: (0, 0, 0, 1)
        color: 1, 1, 1, 1
        pos: 0,520
        size: 800, 80

<Three>
    name: "three"
    Image:
        source: '***********'
        y: self.parent.y
        x: self.parent.x
        allow_stretch: True
        size: 800, 750
    Button:
        text: 'Back To Menu'
        id: button
        font_size: 40
        size: 300, 60
        size_hint: None, None
        on_release: app.root.current = "menu"
        pos: 100,13
    Button:
        text: root.a + ' WITH ' + root.b
        font_size: 40
        text_size: self.width, None
        size_hint: None, None
        halign: 'center'
        background_color: (0, 0, 0, 1)
        color: 1, 1, 1, 1
        pos: 0,520
        size: 800, 80

<Four>
    name: "four"
    Image:
        source: '*************'
        y: self.parent.y
        x: self.parent.x
        allow_stretch: True
        size: 800, 750
    Button:
        text: 'Back To Menu'
        id: button
        font_size: 40
        size: 300, 60
        size_hint: None, None
        on_release: app.root.current = "menu"
        pos: 100,13
    Button:
        text: root.a + ' WITH ' + root.b
        font_size: 40
        text_size: self.width, None
        size_hint: None, None
        halign: 'center'
        background_color: (0, 0, 0, 1)
        color: 1, 1, 1, 1
        pos: 0,520
        size: 800, 80

<Five>
    name: "five"
    Image:
        source: '********************'
        y: self.parent.y
        x: self.parent.x
        allow_stretch: True
        size: 800, 750
    Button:
        text: 'Back To Menu'
        id: button
        font_size: 40
        size: 300, 60
        size_hint: None, None
        on_release: app.root.current = "menu"
        pos: 100,13
    Button:
        text: root.a + ' WITH ' + root.b
        font_size: 40
        text_size: self.width, None
        size_hint: None, None
        halign: 'center'
        background_color: (0, 0, 0, 1)
        color: 1, 1, 1, 1
        pos: 0,520
        size: 800, 80

<Six>
    name: "six"
    Image:
        source: '************'
        y: self.parent.y
        x: self.parent.x
        allow_stretch: True
        size: 800, 750
    Button:
        text: 'Back To Menu'
        id: button
        font_size: 40
        size: 300, 60
        size_hint: None, None
        on_release: app.root.current = "menu"
        pos: 100,13
    Button:
        text: root.a + ' WITH ' + root.b
        font_size: 40
        text_size: self.width, None
        size_hint: None, None
        halign: 'center'
        background_color: (0, 0, 0, 1)
        color: 1, 1, 1, 1
        pos: 0,520
        size: 800, 80

<Seven>
    name: "seven"
    Image:
        source: '*******************'
        y: self.parent.y
        x: self.parent.x
        allow_stretch: True
        size: 800, 750
    Button:
        text: 'Back To Menu'
        id: button
        font_size: 40
        size: 300, 60
        size_hint: None, None
        on_release: app.root.current = "menu"
        pos: 100,13
    Button:
        text: root.a + ' WITH ' + root.b
        font_size: 40
        text_size: self.width, None
        size_hint: None, None
        halign: 'center'
        background_color: (0, 0, 0, 1)
        color: 1, 1, 1, 1
        pos: 0,520
        size: 800, 80

<Eight>
    name: "eight"
    Image:
        source: '********************'
        y: self.parent.y
        x: self.parent.x
        allow_stretch: True
        size: 800, 750      
    Button:
        text: 'Back To Menu'
        id: button
        font_size: 40
        size: 300, 60
        size_hint: None, None
        on_release: app.root.current = "menu"
        pos: 100,13
    Button:
        text: root.a + ' WITH ' + root.b
        font_size: 40
        text_size: self.width, None
        size_hint: None, None
        halign: 'center'
        background_color: (0, 0, 0, 1)
        color: 1, 1, 1, 1
        pos: 0,520
        size: 800, 80

<Nine>
    name: "nine"
    Image:
        source: '***************'
        y: self.parent.y
        x: self.parent.x
        allow_stretch: True
        size: 800, 750
    Button:
        text: 'Back To Menu'
        id: button
        font_size: 40
        size: 300, 60
        size_hint: None, None
        on_release: app.root.current = "menu"
        pos: 100,13
    Button:
        text: root.a + ' WITH ' + root.b
        font_size: 40
        text_size: self.width, None
        size_hint: None, None
        halign: 'center'
        background_color: (0, 0, 0, 1)
        color: 1, 1, 1, 1
        pos: 0,520
        size: 800, 80
```

i am new to python and kivy both and this is the last thing which is holding me up from building my first app.i would be very thankful if someone could help me out.

Comment: The text for your `Button` in `ScreenFive` is `root.a + ' with ' + root.b`. The values of `root.a` and `root.b` are set by reading your files when you start the `App`, and you have not implemented any other way  for `root.a` and `root.b` to be updated, so they will not change.

Comment: Also, you code above is not a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). In fact, it won't even run. Please update the code in your question to make a MCVE.

Comment: hey john anderson,

Comment: thanks for your attention, i have updated the code please have a look at it. looking forward for a reply.

Comment: the code runs absolutely fine with just this glitch. my doubt in precise is :

Comment: SINCE the values of root.a and root.b are set by reading the files when i start the App, HOW TO  implement a way for root.a and root.b to be updated, so they WILL change.

Answer (score 0):

First, some problems with your code. In every case where you have:

```
a = StringProperty()
b = StringProperty()
```

in your class definition, you follow it with:

```
a = myfile.readline(14)
```

and

```
b = myfile.readline(14)
```

That replaces your `StringProperty` with an ordinary `String`, and so eliminates the link with references like `root.a` and `root.b` in the `kv` file.

In order to get this to work, I changed your definition of `ScreenFive` to:

```
class ScreenFive(Screen):
    box = ScreenFour()
    a = StringProperty()
    b = StringProperty()

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(ScreenFive, self).__init__(**kwargs)

        myfile = open('grouptextinput.txt','r')
        print 'file is opened'
        self.a = myfile.readline(14)
        print self.a

        myfile = open('disabilitytextinput.txt','r')
        print 'file is opened'
        self.b = myfile.readline(14)
        print self.b
```

The above keeps `a` and `b` as `StringProperty` and allows the `kv` bindings to work. The next step is to update `a` and `b` in `ScreenFive` when you want the values to change. To do this, I modified your `submit_textinput` method in `ScreenFour` as:

```
def submit_textinput(self):
    self.grouptextinput = self.group_text_input.text
    print("group of people: {}".format(self.grouptextinput))
    App.get_running_app().sm.get_screen("screenfive").a = self.grouptextinput
    self.save()

    self.disabilitytextinput = self.disability_text_input.text
    print("with following disability: {}".format(self.disabilitytextinput))
    App.get_running_app().sm.get_screen("screenfive").b = self.disabilitytextinput
    self.save2()
```

The lines:

```
App.get_running_app().sm.get_screen("screenfive").a = self.grouptextinput
```

and:

```
App.get_running_app().sm.get_screen("screenfive").b = self.disabilitytextinput
```

update the `StringProperty` values in `ScreenFive`.

I also changed your `MainApp`:

```
class MainApp(App):

    def build(self):
        self.sm = presentation
        return presentation
```

to keep a reference to the `ScreenManager`.